# Node app with Python module in project on Heroku not installing

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, pip

I have a Node (Express server) project deployed to Heroku which runs fine, but I have a small Python module I wrote that doesn't need a server or new Heroku instance, but it needs to install some 3rd party packages from pip.

My problem is that while Python seems to run fine (a `print()` works in .py file perfectly) it doesn't install the modules. I ran `pip freeze` and added the `requirements.txt` file to the root of my project. The file looks like:

```
funcy==1.6
numpy==1.10.2
scipy==0.16.1
```

But when I deploy Heroku doesn't detect any python and doesn't seem to install them and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "src/blm/algo.py", line 4, in <module> from package import mvo File "/app/src/blm/package/mvo.py", line 1, in <module> import numpy as np ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

The output from Heroku

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 5.8.0...
       Using default npm version: 3.7.3
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Pruning any extraneous modules
       Installing node modules (package.json)

       > my-project@0.0.1 postinstall /tmp/build_c845357a6a491eb02f8ad4b043020ac6/my-project-7f7e7fe8632473e1f1f88f430b040396fb10671f
       > webpack --config ./webpack-production.config.js --progress --colors

Hash: 2ceaeac5876ff2e2463e
       Version: webpack 1.12.14
       Time: 15178ms
       Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       bundle.js  455 kB       0  [emitted]  main
       main.css   15 kB       0  [emitted]  main
       + 272 hidden modules
       Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
       + 2 hidden modules
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
       ├── babel-core@6.7.2
       ├── babel-loader@6.2.4
       ├── babel-preset-es2015@6.6.0
       ├── babel-preset-react@6.5.0
       ├── babel-preset-stage-0@6.5.0
       ├── bcrypt@0.8.5
       ├── css-loader@0.23.1
       ├── d3@3.5.16
       ├── d3pie@0.1.9
       ├── express@4.13.4
       ├── extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
       ├── jquery@2.2.2
       ├── node-sass@3.4.2
       ├── node-uuid@1.4.7
       ├── react@0.14.7
       ├── react-dom@0.14.7
       ├── react-redux@4.4.1
       ├── react-router@2.0.1
       ├── redux@3.3.1
       ├── sass-loader@3.2.0
       ├── style-loader@0.13.0
       └── webpack@1.12.14

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 30M
-----> Launching...
       Released v13
       https://my-project.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

===UPDATE===

I also tried adding a "pipinstall" worker to see if it would install but nothing happened.

Procfile:

```
web: node server.js
pipinstall: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need multiple buildpacksfor your app.

Run the following:

heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

Then, add the following in a file called .buildpacks in your project's root directory:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
```

Alternatively, you can use heroku toolbelt commands (heroku buildpacks:set and heroku buildpacks:add) to configure your multiple buildpacks, as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

Comment: This is how I did it, but for the record, SciPy (which the o.p. was trying to install) is not officially supported according to [this page of Heroku's Python guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps). It looks like there is a [workaround](https://github.com/thenovices/heroku-buildpack-scipy), but just the use of the Node and Python buildpacks is pushing dyno memory limit.