# Python and Node.js on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I have started to make a Node server which runs on Heroku. It was working fine until I tried to use the (unofficial) Duolingo API. I wrote the following Python script to connect to the API:

```
import duolingo
import simplejson as json

lingo  = duolingo.Duolingo('harleyrowland')
print json.dumps(lingo.get_user_info())
```

and my Node server uses it using the following commands:

```
var python = require('python-shell');

module.exports = {
  getData: function(callback){
    python.run('duoScript.py', function (err, results) { 
      console.log(err);
      console.log(results);
      var res = JSON.parse(results);
      var language = res.language_data.es.language_string;
      var streak = res.language_data.es.streak;
      var level = res.language_data.es.level;
      var levelPerecentage = res.language_data.es.level_percent;
      var fluency = res.language_data.es.fluency_score;
      var nextLesson = res.language_data.es.next_lesson.skill_title;
      return callback({language, streak, level, levelPerecentage, fluency, nextLesson});
    });
  }
}
```

which all works totally fine locally.

When I pushed this to Heroku, the code didn't work and I started to get the following error in the Heroku logs:

```
{ [Error: ImportError: No module named duolingo]
     2016-10-06T00:02:32.133315+00:00 app[web.1]:   traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "duoScript.py", line 1, in <module>\n    import duolingo\nImportError: No module named duolingo\n',
    executable: 'python',
    options: null,
    script: 'duoScript.py',
    args: null,
    exitCode: 1 
}
```

Because of this, I went on the [Heroku API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#the-basics) and found that I needed to add a requirements.txt file. So I did:

```
duolingo-api==0.3
simplejson==3.8.2
```

which still didn't work. I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167012/node-app-with-python-module-in-project-on-heroku-not-installing) answer and added a .buildpacks file:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
```

and I still get the same error.

Any idea what is causing this error?

## Update 1

Thought I would show my Procfile too incase this was the problem:

```
web: node index.js
pipinstall: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

## Update 2

Output of `git push heroku master` without `pipinstall`:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 288 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  5.9.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.9.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.7.3
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── ejs@2.4.1 extraneous
remote:        ├── emailjs@1.0.8 extraneous
remote:        ├── express@4.13.3
remote:        ├── http-status@0.2.3
remote:        ├── nodemailer@1.4.0
remote:        ├── nodemailer-smtp-transport@1.0.4
remote:        ├── python-shell@0.4.0
remote:        └── xoauth2@1.2.0
remote:        
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 13M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v25
remote:        https://arcane-anchorage-33274.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

Comment: Remove the `pipinstall` from your Procfile and post the output of your git push

Comment: @RetoAebersold Just updated my question

Comment: Did you do the following:
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

Comment: Yes. I still get the same error afterwards.

Comment: Remove the buildpack multi and use https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: @RetoAebersold Ah great! It is working now! Do you want to make an answer so I can accept it or shall I just write one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to remove the deprecated [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) and use the Heroku [`buildpacks`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 heroku/python
$ heroku buildpacks
=== foobar Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/python
```

From the docs:

> The buildpack for the primary language of your app should always be the last buildpack in the list. This ensures that defaults for that primary language are applied instead of those for another language, and allows Heroku to correctly detect the primary language of your app.

Comment: @Haych are you facing any memory issues in your heroku dyno with this approach?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe useful for some: if you are deploying via GitHub (and not via the Heroku CLI), you can add buildpacks for other languages in your Heroku dashboard under the Settings tab .