# ModuleNotFoundError when running .PY file from Nodejs on Heroku

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, pip

My Nodejs webserver runs a python file on Heroku. Logs show following error:

```
2021-12-23T18:54:48 app[web.1]: File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-12-23T18:54:48 app[web.1]: import instaloader
2021-12-23T18:54:48 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instaloader'
```

requirements.txt

```
instaloader==4.8.2
requests==2.26.0
pymongo==4.0.1
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.6.15
```

When adding the python buildpack the entire application stops working. Note: Im not running a python webserver, just this one file from nodejs. Everything works locally.

Comment: instead of pip3 install -r requirements.txt, use `python -m pip install -r requirement.txt`

Comment: @sahasrara62 "all requirements already satisfied" another push to heroku changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

By default, Heroku will only build your code with a single [Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), which as you mentioned seems to be their [NodeJS buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs). In order to also be able to run Python code in the same dyno, it is easiest to [use multiple buildpacks for your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app). This can be used to install & configure both your node dependencies as well as your Python dependencies.

A very similar question with a good answer was [already posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39947385/17758344). You should be able to follow the same commands.