# How to use BeautifulSoup4 in Heroku

Tags: python

I'm wondering how to use BeautifulSoup4 on the Heroku Server.

In my requirements.txt file I have written: "BeautifulSoup==4.9.1",

but I get an Error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement BeautifulSoup==4 (from -r /tmp/build_d624b770_/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for BeautifulSoup==4 (from -r /tmp/build_d624b770_/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

So how can I use BeautifulSoup4 then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add python dependencies to heroku node server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723448/how-to-add-python-dependencies-to-heroku-node-server)

Comment: Not really :( But still thank you :D @Joona Yoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cant see your `requirements.txt` file, from seeing the error I am assuming it has something like `BeautifulSoup==4`, but the way of installing BeautifulSoup is `pip install bs4` since its not like version 4 of BS, its is bs4 itself, so you `requirements.txt` must contain `bs4==0.0.0` or `bs4==0.0.1` or just plain `bs4` with any other dependencies

Learn more about BS4 releases [here](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/#history)

Comment: Nice, now it's installing bs4 version 0.0.1 :D And since this is working, I have another problem :P I want also to install smtplib... But I get the same Error. In my requirements.txt I have "smtplib==3.9"

Comment: Thats the same issue, `pip install secure-smtplib` is the actual installation, so it must be `secure-smtplib==0.1.1` assumingyou want latest version https://pypi.org/project/secure-smtplib/#history